# python matplotlib library is not working outside Anaconda3\scripts folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am a newbie,my program having matplotlib library is running only within anaconda3\scripts folder where idle is.matplotlib library is not working within any other directories.i tried changing the path variable with the directory path,but no use.
tried to import and run:

```
import matplotlib
```

result:

```
   ======== RESTART: C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\Scripts\python\matplot1.py ========

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\Scripts\python\matplot1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib

  File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals.six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

  File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 90, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()

  File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 158, in _resolve
    module = _import_module(self.mod)

  File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 80, in _import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 86, in <module>
    import email

 File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\Scripts\python\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib

File "C:\Users\manaf\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package
>>>
```

Comment: It looks like you have your installations crossed.  See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html for how to create and manage environments.  Are you sure you are using the correct python binary?

Comment: oh ,i am embarassed,its my own mistake, i have an email.py custom program within my working directory.changed name,now working perfectly,